# Pass Multiple Items in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I am new in Android. I am in a learning faze. I want to show result like below image[image]

Here is my logic what I am doing in my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] imagesList = new String[4];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        imagesList[i] = "Image "+ i;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> stringAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.activity_main,
            R.id.textView,
            new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(imagesList))
    );
    setListAdapter(stringAdapter);
}
```

One more thing that string size can be change. Currently it is 4 it can be 10 or any other integer. If number increase then I will apply swiper but currently I not need that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Grid view for what you want to achieve http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Another way is to make your own custom ArrayAdapter and use for each row a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and 4 TextView, each TextView representing a column.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] val={
            "one",
            "two",
            "Three",
            "four",
            "five",
            "six",
            "seven"
            };
    ListView lt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lt1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); //lt1=instance of Listview which is declared globally

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, val);
    lt1.setAdapter(adapter);
    lt1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated 2method stub
            //clicked item index 
            int itemPosition=position;

            //list item clicked value
            String itemvalue=(String)lt1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position: "+itemPosition+"Listitem: "+itemvalue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: by this code you can add multiple items by using arrayAdapter with ListView

Comment: @YogitabaJadeja this will only list all the data as currently my code is listing.